# How to locate services by version with Netflix eureka and ribbon

Tags: java, cloud, service-discovery, netflix

We're currently exploring [Flux Capacitor](https://github.com/cfregly/fluxcapacitor) from Netflix to study their implementation of micro-service architectures. Our interests, at the moment, are focused on service registration and dynamic look-up functionality.

Browsing through the code, samples, and configuration, but something's not clear; **service versioning**. If [eureka](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka) provides discovery services, and [ribbon](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon) is eureka-based REST client, how does a client say it needs service `1.2` of service `fooBar`? Where does the client store/get that version number; from a local config file like [this](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/blob/master/ribbon-examples/src/main/resources/sample-client.properties), or is it dynamically-obtained through [archaius](https://github.com/Netflix/archaius)?

Comment: Can you explain your need for service versioning with a real world scenario?

Comment: Very interesting question and links, thanks for pointing me in this direction!

Comment: Sample scenario: let's say I want to deploy a new version of some 'customerReview' service introducing non backward compatible changes, without having to migrate all other services calling it at once. So I have to keep both the old and the new versions of customerReview running, at least temporarily. To keep code clean, I want to avoid duplicate 'versioned' endpoints within the same service instance. So far I can't think of anything better than deploying under different spring.application.name and using versioning in the URL to route requests…

Comment: @yoann-h you're right, it requires deploying multiple versions of the same service, typical of any micro-service landscape

Answer (score 7):

I can't see any built-in way of handling service versions in the [documentation](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations) for the Eureka REST API.

Therefore I think the best way of handling this would be to incorporate versioning information in your service IDs.

Let's say we have 4 services: *User*, *Statistics*, *Login*, and *oAuth*.

We've just updated the *User* service API to change functionality required for some new requirements in the *Login* service. These changes are however incompatible with the API that *oAuth* is using and no one has the time to update that service. The *Statistics* service isn't using any of this functionality so it doesn't care which version of the API is used. This means we need both the new version of the *User* service (1.2) and the old version (1.1) running at the same time.

We can set it up like this:

- The configuration for the *User* 1.1 services says to register as "user-1.1" *and* "user"
- The configuration for the *User* 1.2 services says to register as "user-1.2" *and* "user"
- The configuration for the *oAuth* service says that the ID of the *User* service is "user-1.1"
- The configuration for the *Login* service says that the ID of the *User* service is "user-1.2"
- The configuration for the *Statistics* service says that the ID of the *User* service is "user"

This way the *oAuth* service will only communicate with the old *User* service, the *Login* service with the new *User* service, and the *Statistics* service with any *User* service.

You should be able to use Archaius to propagate the configuration to the servers.

Note that if you release *User* version 1.3 that introduces changes incompatible with the parts of 1.2 and 1.1 that the *Statistics* service is using you will either have to tell the *User* 1.1 and 1.2 services to register themselves as something else too (like "user-statistics-safe") and tell the *Statistics* service to use that ID, or tell the *Statistics* service to use either "user-1.1" or "user-1.2".

Comment: Sounds good. Could you please elaborate a bit on how you would achieve the multiple registering? (For now I'm only using basic registering with service name based on the spring.application.name property)

Comment: It seems to be a bit tricky to achieve with the Java libraries. The REST API definitely supports it but the underlying classes seem to only work with one instance configuration. What you could do is create a separate `DiscoveryClient` for each alias. You'll have to set it up yourself though, so have a look at how spring-cloud [does it](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration.java) for inspiration.

Comment: I also suggest you [sumbit a feature request](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/issues) for support for aliases in `DiscoveryClient`.

Comment: Indeed, that might justify a feature request. I'll dig a bit more and submit one. That may also lead to explanations about some alternative solutions. I'll try to update this topic with my findings.

Comment: What about if a bug is found in user-1.6 down to user-1.1?
Wouldn't this approach require a branch per version? A CI/CD pipeline per version? Wouldn't this mean passing all the complexity to DevOps?

Answer (score 1):

**Service 1** registers **v1** and **v2** with **Eureka**

**Service 2** discovers and sends requests to **Service 1**'s v1 and v2 using different **Ribbon** clients

I got this demo to work using `Spring Cloud` though blog could found at: http://tech.asimio.net/2017/03/06/Multi-version-Service-Discovery-using-Spring-Cloud-Netflix-Eureka-and-Ribbon.html

The idea I followed was for `RestTemplate` to use a different `Ribbon` client for each version because each client has its own `ServerListFilter`.

The multi-version service includes the version in registration metadata.

---

**Service 1**

**application.yml**

```
...
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8000/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: ${hostName}
    statusPageUrlPath: ${management.context-path}/info
    healthCheckUrlPath: ${management.context-path}/health
    preferIpAddress: true
    metadataMap:
      instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${server.port}

---
spring:
   profiles: v1
eureka:
  instance:
    metadataMap:
      versions: v1

---
spring:
   profiles: v1v2
eureka:
  instance:
    metadataMap:
      versions: v1,v2
...
```

---

**Service 2**

**application.yml**

```
...
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8000/eureka/

demo-multiversion-registration-api-1-v1:
   ribbon:
     # Eureka vipAddress of the target service
     DeploymentContextBasedVipAddresses: demo-multiversion-registration-api-1
     NIWSServerListClassName: com.netflix.niws.loadbalancer.DiscoveryEnabledNIWSServerList
     # Interval to refresh the server list from the source (ms)
     ServerListRefreshInterval: 30000

demo-multiversion-registration-api-1-v2:
   ribbon:
     # Eureka vipAddress of the target service
     DeploymentContextBasedVipAddresses: demo-multiversion-registration-api-1
     NIWSServerListClassName: com.netflix.niws.loadbalancer.DiscoveryEnabledNIWSServerList
     # Interval to refresh the server list from the source (ms)
     ServerListRefreshInterval: 30000
...
```

**Application.java**

```
...
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {
    "com.asimio.api.multiversion.demo2.config",
    "com.asimio.api.multiversion.demo2.rest"
})
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**AppConfig.java** (See how the `Ribbon` client name matches the `Ribbon` key found in **application.yml**

```
...
@Configuration
@RibbonClients(value = {
    @RibbonClient(name = "demo-multiversion-registration-api-1-v1", configuration = RibbonConfigDemoApi1V1.class),
    @RibbonClient(name = "demo-multiversion-registration-api-1-v2", configuration = RibbonConfigDemoApi1V2.class)
})
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean(name = "loadBalancedRestTemplate")
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate loadBalancedRestTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

**RibbonConfigDemoApi1V1.java**

```
...
public class RibbonConfigDemoApi1V1 {

    private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

    @Bean
    public ServerListFilter<Server> serverListFilter() {
        return new VersionedNIWSServerListFilter<>(this.discoveryClient, RibbonClientApi.DEMO_REGISTRATION_API_1_V1);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setDiscoveryClient(DiscoveryClient discoveryClient) {
        this.discoveryClient = discoveryClient;
    }
}
```

**RibbonConfigDemoApi1V2.java** is similar but using `RibbonClientApi.DEMO_REGISTRATION_API_1_V2`

**RibbonClientApi.java**

```
...
public enum RibbonClientApi {

    DEMO_REGISTRATION_API_1_V1("demo-multiversion-registration-api-1", "v1"),

    DEMO_REGISTRATION_API_1_V2("demo-multiversion-registration-api-1", "v2");

    public final String serviceId;
    public final String version;

    private RibbonClientApi(String serviceId, String version) {
        this.serviceId = serviceId;
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

**VersionedNIWSServerListFilter.java**

```
...
public class VersionedNIWSServerListFilter<T extends Server> extends DefaultNIWSServerListFilter<T> {

    private static final String VERSION_KEY = "versions";

    private final DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;
    private final RibbonClientApi ribbonClientApi;

    public VersionedNIWSServerListFilter(DiscoveryClient discoveryClient, RibbonClientApi ribbonClientApi) {
        this.discoveryClient = discoveryClient;
        this.ribbonClientApi = ribbonClientApi;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> getFilteredListOfServers(List<T> servers) {
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
        List<ServiceInstance> serviceInstances = this.discoveryClient.getInstances(this.ribbonClientApi.serviceId);
        for (ServiceInstance serviceInstance : serviceInstances) {
            List<String> versions = this.getInstanceVersions(serviceInstance);
            if (versions.isEmpty() || versions.contains(this.ribbonClientApi.version)) {
                result.addAll(this.findServerForVersion(servers, serviceInstance));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private List<String> getInstanceVersions(ServiceInstance serviceInstance) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        String rawVersions = serviceInstance.getMetadata().get(VERSION_KEY);
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(rawVersions)) {
            result.addAll(Arrays.asList(rawVersions.split(",")));
        }
        return result;
    }
...
```

**AggregationResource.java**

```
...
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/aggregation", produces = "application/json")
public class AggregationResource {

    private static final String ACTORS_SERVICE_ID_V1 = "demo-multiversion-registration-api-1-v1";
    private static final String ACTORS_SERVICE_ID_V2 = "demo-multiversion-registration-api-1-v2";

    private RestTemplate loadBalancedRestTemplate;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/v1/actors/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public com.asimio.api.multiversion.demo2.model.v1.Actor findActorV1(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) {
        String url = String.format("http://%s/v1/actors/{id}", ACTORS_SERVICE_ID_V1);
        return this.loadBalancedRestTemplate.getForObject(url, com.asimio.api.multiversion.demo2.model.v1.Actor.class, id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/v2/actors/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public com.asimio.api.multiversion.demo2.model.v2.Actor findActorV2(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) {
        String url = String.format("http://%s/v2/actors/{id}", ACTORS_SERVICE_ID_V2);
        return this.loadBalancedRestTemplate.getForObject(url, com.asimio.api.multiversion.demo2.model.v2.Actor.class, id);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setLoadBalancedRestTemplate(RestTemplate loadBalancedRestTemplate) {
        this.loadBalancedRestTemplate = loadBalancedRestTemplate;
    }
}
```